# Liouville Lambda Function and Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: reference-request, riemann-hypothesis, open-problem, liouville-function

What is the exact statement involving the Liouville Lambda function, which is equivalent to Riemann Hypothesis, and true iff RH is true? Can anyone cite the sources for it and/or outline its proof in brief?

Just curious, because hardly any literature available regarding it, unlike other equivalent problems of RH. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wikipedia gives the definition of the function... you should not ask question before you try to resolve your question.

Comment: Thanks, @Riemann, I have edited the question now. Kindly help if you can.

Comment: @Riemann On the Wikipedia page, it defines the function and also talks about the connection between its summatory function $L(n)$ and Pólya problem, but not much is found regarding RH.

Comment: Wow, you got a response from Riemann himself! Perhaps @Louiville will chime in as well?

Comment: Perhaps this? https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-59969-4_9, also available at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307577874_The_Liouville_function_and_the_Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: @joriki Haha, true. I was honestly going to write the same thing. Nothing is better than Riemann himself explaining RH. Anyways, thanks for the reference-request tag, was searching for that.

Comment: Google found this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307577874_The_Liouville_function_and_the_Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot @lhf . I will have a look at it

Comment: BTW, if anyone has the knowledge, please tell me if we can use the "limit of a sum" property and apply it on the summatory function $L(n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ we have $\sum_{n \geq 1} \lambda(n)/n^s = \zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$, which is analogous to $\sum_{n \geq 1} \mu(n)/n^s = 1/\zeta(s)$ for the Mobius function. Set $L(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \lambda(n)$, which is analogous to the function $M(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n)$.

There is a link between the functions $\lambda$ and $\mu$: $\lambda(n) = \sum_{d^2 \mid n} \mu(n/d^2)$ for all $n \geq 1$, where the sum runs over squares dividing $n$. Show that implies $L(x) = \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} M(x/d^2)$ for all $x \geq 1$, which is a link between $L$ and $M$ that lets us convert some properties of $M$ into similar properties of $L$.

Let's show RH is equivalent to the bound $L(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, where the $O$-constant is allowed to depend on $\varepsilon$. This is the $L$-analogue of RH being equivalent to the bound $M(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, which is more widely accessible in the literature.

To show RH implies $L(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$,  use the equation $L(x) = \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} M(x/d^2)$ to show that *if* $M(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for an $\varepsilon > 0$, then $L(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for the same $\varepsilon$. It should be easier for you to find a proof in the literature that RH implies the estimate $M(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, so RH implies $L(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ too.

To show, conversely, that the bound $L(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ implies RH, start with the equation
$$
\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\lambda(n)}{n^s} = s\int_1^\infty \frac{L(x)}{x^{s+1}}\,dx 
$$
when ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$. We already know $\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbf C$, so $\zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbf C$.
When $L(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for an $\varepsilon > 0$, show the integral on the right side is absolutely convergent when ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2 + \varepsilon$, which implies the right side is analytic for such $s$. Thus $\zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$ is analytic when ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2 + \varepsilon$. If there is an $s_0$ where $\zeta(s_0) = 0$ and ${\rm Re}(s_0) > 1/2 + \varepsilon$ then $\zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s_0$ because
$\zeta(2s)$ is analytic and nonvanishing when ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$.  We have contradicted analyticity of $\zeta(2s)/\zeta(s)$ when ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2 + \varepsilon$, so the bound $L(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ implies the zeta-function has no zeros with real part greater than $1/2 + \varepsilon$.   So if $L(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, then $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros with ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$, which is RH.

If you have ever seen a proof that the bound $M(x) = O(x^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ implies RH, you should recognize that the previous paragraph is essentially the same argument, with the role of the displayed integral identity above for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ replacing the identity
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s} = s\int_1^\infty \frac{M(x)}{x^{s+1}}\,dx 
$$
for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$.

The reason you probably don't see much written directly about relationships between RH and the Liouville function is that formulating and proving such results at a basic level is always just an exercise in adapting what is more widely written about $\mu(n)$ or $M(x)$, as I illustrated above.

Here are two things to try yourself.

1. Locate a proof that the prime number theorem is equivalent to $M(x) = o(x)$ and adapt that method to prove the prime number theorem is equivalent to $L(x) = o(x)$.
2. Locate a proof that RH is  equivalent to convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 1} \mu(n)/n^s$ for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$ and adapt that method to prove RH is equivalent to convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 1} \lambda(n)/n^s$ for ${\rm Re}(s) > 1/2$. This is a second equivalence between RH and the Liouville function. (The series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \lambda(n)/n^s$ and $\sum_{n \geq 1} \mu(n)/n^s$ turn out not to converge anywhere on ${\rm Re}(s) = 1/2$, which is analogous to $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^s$ not converging anywhere on ${\rm Re}(s) > 1$ and is not as technical to prove as the RH equivalences.)

Comment: Thank you very very much for such a detailed and comprehensive answer. It was unexpected that someone would take so much effort.

Comment: If you have the knowledge, please tell me if we can use the "limit of a sum" property and apply it on the summatory function of $\lambda(n)$ i.e. $L(n)$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "limit of a sum" property.  And don't write $L(n)$ instead of $L(x)$: the $n$ in $\lambda(n)$ is an integer variable while the $x$ in $L(x)$ is a real variable.

Comment: I looked in your post history and it appears you might be trying to prove RH. With your current background, I do not think that is a good use of your time.

Comment: In a sum, when all the individual terms' limits exist, the limit of a sum is the sum of each of the limits. If I'm not wrong, this is called as the limit of a sum property in calculus. So my question was regarding that property

Comment: And even though I agree that my post history might look like that, but I'm not into solving or proving RH, as I know I got no chance there :-) It's just like I was curious about knowing and understanding the equivalent problems of RH in detail

Comment: I don't understand what it means to apply a "limit of a sum" property that you described to $L(x)$: the terms in that sum are simply integers.  In $L(100) = \sum_{n \leq 100} \lambda(n)$ there is nothing to be taking a limit of in the terms of this finite sum.